# Probability- The number of children in a family

Tags: probability-theory

A family has $j$ children with probability $p_j$ , where $p_1 = 0.4, p_2 = 0.2, p_3 = 0.1, p_4 = 0.3$. A child from this family is randomly chosen. Given that this child is the eldest child in the family, find the conditional probability that the family has

1. only one child;
2. 3 children;
3. 2 children.

And when the randomly selected child is the youngest child in the family?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem?

Comment: @paw88789 If we assume that E- the probability that the chosen child is the eldest and that F- the probability that there are n children, we should compute the conditional probability P(F\E). But there is smth wrong with my assumptions and actually I don't know what to do.

Comment: Are sections 2 and 3 supposed to confuse the reader on purpose?

Comment: @barakmanos I don't know, that might be just different additional conditions. But they are definitely more confusing than 1.

Comment: What do you mean, "I don't know"??? You wrote this question, why on earth did you choose to write these sections the way you did? How does it help you to get an answer to your question, by confusing the readers with this awkward structure???

Comment: @barakmanos that question is not created by me, and moreover what is unclear there? In the first section we take into consideration that there is only one child, and in the second one - that there are two children.

Comment: The 2nd one says "3 children", and the 3rd one says "2 children"!!! That is definitely an unnecessary confusion added to the question. And BTW, this is not a "do my homework for free" service. At least pretend like you're trying to hide the fact that you've copy-pasted this question from your homework assignment. Write it down properly, and add your thoughts, progress and general effort made towards reaching the solution on your own. Then describe what part you're having a problem with.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a start:

Let's look at the case of the family having one child ($F_1$) given that the eldest was picked ($E$).

$$P(F_1 | E)=\frac{P(F_1\cap E)}{P(E)}=\frac{P(F_1)}{P(E)}=\frac{.4}{.4+\frac{1}{2}(.2)+\frac13 (.1)+\frac14 (.3)}$$

Comment: I understood everything except the last calculations in denominator. How did you get those numbers?

Comment: I think I understand now. So when there are two children the only thing that changes is the number in the numerator? Now it should be 0.2?

Answer (score 0):

I will edit this answer farther more, just would like to raise few points.
Before the points, the main idea is to think which information the knowledge of the chosen child to be the eldest gives us about the event.

1. In the event of case (a) we learn nothing from "Choosing" the eldest boy as the family has only 1 child.
2. In cases (b) and (c) you need to think about the probability of the the required number of children to happen and choosing the eldest of them.
   Namely, If we have a family of 2 children, what's the probability to chose the elder one?
3. I'm not sure about (d), if they meant the chosen child is the eldest and the youngest, well it happen in the event of (a) only.

All those can and should be solved using "[Bayes Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem)".